# How to find out what event cause a javascript function to be executed in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm debugging an old Infragistic grid.  One of the javascript functions executes more times than needed.  It was coded to be executed when a user clicks a cell in the grid.  However, sometimes it runs when on mouse is over the cell.  I'd like to know if there's a way to track what event caused this function to run.

Multiple executions of that function happens only in FireFox, IE behaves as it intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug has a really helpful debugger : http://getfirebug.com/js.html

There is a nice tutorial [here](http://thecodecentral.com/2007/08/01/debug-javascript-with-firebug) that will tell you all what you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

The most awesome css, javascript, html, dom, everything-else extension: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue of event bubbling. Check to see if any elements containing your event also handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to track the event is to make a syntax error within the event handler, f.e. `alert(non_existing_object)`. When the error is encounterd, Firebug shows function call stack trace (must be set before in it's settings).